# Cannot call value of non-function type double

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mobile, compiler-errors

I am quite new to programing in swift and I am working on a music app for iOS that adjusts the font size of the text in a UILabel in proportion to the string's length. In my code, I am trying to count the number of characters in the string statement and have it plugged into a formula, but for some reason Xcode gives me the error: **Cannot call value of non function type double** I tried setting the value to a CGFloat but it still gives me the same error on the "let b = 41.2 - .8(a) line. Thank you so much and sorry if this seems like a basic question.

```
let title = "Let It Bleed"
    AlbumName.text = title
    let a  = title.characters.count

   if ( a <= 19){

    let b = 41.2 - .8(a)
        let fontsize = CGFloat(b)
       AlbumName.font = AlbumName.font.fontWithSize(fontsize)

    }
```

[A screenshot of the code with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFuYS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you expect "0.8 times a" with `.8(a)`.

Three things:

- You need leading 0 to represent fractional values in Swift.
- You need explicit operator `*` for multiplication.
- You need to convert numeric types to match for mathematical operations.

All these included, your line of interest becomes like this:

```
let b = 41.2 - 0.8 * CGFloat(a)
```